# GPU Out of Memory deep learning UNET network with tensorflow. How to solve it?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

My question is how to calculate the ram memory need to run a deep learning network?
I am asking this question because, my training for some network configuration is getting out of memory.

If the tensorflow only store the memory necessary to the  tunable parameteres, and if I have around 8 million, I supposed the ram required will be:

Ram = 8.000.000 * (8 (float64)) / 1.000.000 (scaling to mb)

Ram = 64 mb, right?

The tensorflow require more memory to store the image at each layer?

How can I add a report to see how much memory have been allocated to it each tensor? What I would like to do is:

```
ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8,64,256,256] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node gradient_tape/functional_1/conv2d_14/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput (defined at <ipython-input-17-d4852b86b8c1>:25) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

By the way this are my GPU Specification:

- Nvdia GeForce 1050 4GB

Networking topology

- Unet
- Input Shape (256,256,4)

```
Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 256, 4) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 256, 256, 64) 2368        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 256, 256, 64) 0           conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 64) 36928       dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 128 73856       max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 128, 128, 128 0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 128 147584      dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 64, 64, 256)  0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 256)  590080      dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 256)  0           conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 512)  1180160     max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 32, 32, 512)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 512)  2359808     dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTranspo (None, 64, 64, 256)  524544      conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 64, 64, 512)  0           conv2d_transpose[0][0]           
                                                                 conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 256)  1179904     concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 64, 64, 256)  0           conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 256)  590080      dropout_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTrans (None, 128, 128, 128 131200      conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 128, 128, 256 0           conv2d_transpose_1[0][0]         
                                                                 conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 295040      concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 128, 128, 128 0           conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 147584      dropout_5[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTrans (None, 256, 256, 64) 32832       conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 256, 256, 128 0           conv2d_transpose_2[0][0]         
                                                                 conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 73792       concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)             (None, 256, 256, 64) 0           conv2d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 36928       dropout_6[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 1)  65          conv2d_13[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 7,697,921
Trainable params: 7,697,921
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**This is the error given.**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d4852b86b8c1> in <module>
     23 # Train the model, doing validation at the end of each epoch.
     24 epochs = 30
---> 25 result_model = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_gen, callbacks=callbacks)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    838         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    839         # stateless function.
--> 840         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    841     else:
    842       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2827     with self._lock:
   2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 
   2831   @property

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1846                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))],
   1847         captured_inputs=self.captured_inputs,
-> 1848         cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1849 
   1850   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1923       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1925     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1926         args,

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    548               inputs=args,
    549               attrs=attrs,
--> 550               ctx=ctx)
    551         else:
    552           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8,64,256,256] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node gradient_tape/functional_1/conv2d_14/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput (defined at <ipython-input-17-d4852b86b8c1>:25) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_17207]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: One important note here, the error you are getting is that your GPU is out of memory, not your RAM. Also, could you provide the code that trains the model? Are you using model.fit or a custom training loop?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the GPU memory. I am using model.fit from tensorflow.

Comment: Please try the suggestions mentioned in the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974373/11530462. Thanks!

Comment: About one of the suggestions, which is: 

* Replacing the 32 bit Floats with 16 bit Floats (if the values fits in that range). 

It should be applied only in input data @tensorflow-support?